# Compilation error when using local dependencies from vendor directory

Tags: go, go-modules

Build (Fails):

```sh
GO111MODULE=off go build -o diameter
```

```sh
[pceuser@pincb-brm02 src]$ echo $GOPATH
```

> /home/pceuser/policy-control-engine

```sh
[pceuser@pincb-brm02 src]$ pwd
```

> /home/pceuser/policy-control-engine/src

```sh
[pceuser@pincb-brm02 src]$ ls
```

> backupgx config.go data.csv go.mod gx.go model.go README redis_test.go  stats.go ccr.go config.yml diameter go.sum Makefile pcediam redis.go server.go vendor

```sh
[pceuser@pincb-brm02 src]$ cd vendor
[pceuser@pincb-brm02 vendor]$ ls
```

> github.com  golang.org  gopkg.in  modules.txt

Error on build:

```
ccr.go:8:2: cannot find package
"github.com/fiorix/go-diameter/v4/diam" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/fiorix/go-diameter/v4/diam (from
$GOROOT)
    /home/pceuser/policy-control-engine/src/github.com/fiorix/go-diameter/v4/diam
(from $GOPATH)

ccr.go:9:2: cannot find package
"github.com/fiorix/go-diameter/v4/diam/avp" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/fiorix/go-diameter/v4/diam/avp (from
$GOROOT)
    /home/pceuser/policy-control-engine/src/github.com/fiorix/go-diameter/v4/diam/avp
(from $GOPATH)

gx.go:11:2: cannot find package
"github.com/fiorix/go-diameter/v4/diam/datatype" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/fiorix/go-diameter/v4/diam/datatype
(from $GOROOT)
    /home/pceuser/policy-control-engine/src/github.com/fiorix/go-diameter/v4/diam/datatype
(from $GOPATH)

ccr.go:6:2: cannot find package
"github.com/fiorix/go-diameter/v4/diam/sm" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/fiorix/go-diameter/v4/diam/sm (from
$GOROOT)
    /home/pceuser/policy-control-engine/src/github.com/fiorix/go-diameter/v4/diam/sm
(from $GOPATH)

redis.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/go-redis/redis" in any
of:     /usr/local/go/src/github.com/go-redis/redis (from $GOROOT)
    /home/pceuser/policy-control-engine/src/github.com/go-redis/redis
(from $GOPATH)

config.go:6:9: cannot find package "gopkg.in/yaml.v2" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/gopkg.in/yaml.v2 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/pceuser/policy-control-engine/src/gopkg.in/yaml.v2 (from
$GOPATH)
```

> Note: I made some changes in https://github.com/fiorix/go-diameter in my
>   vendor dependency folder but still, I am unable to compile it.

Comment: Have you tried `go build -mod=vendor`? This will load your dependencies from `vendor` package instead of finding them in global GOPATH

Comment: There are tricks you can try and that might even work, but to know really the exact reason on why it's happening, I need some additional info. Can you once check if the said packages exist in the vendor directory. Also, share the output of `go env` and `go version`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are outside `GOPATH` and do not use `go modules` and still trying to compile your project by using `vendor` folder, it is worth to try:

```golang
go build -mod=vendor
```

This prevents finding dependencies in the global `GOPATH` and will load your dependencies directly from `vendor` folder.